# Python combine 2 lists based on given key

Tags: python, list

I am dealing with a problem, here is the input

```
list1 = ['A', 'U', 'C', 'C', 'A']
list2 = ['12', '14']
key = {'A12':'*', 'C14':'#'}
```

the output like this:

```
output1 = [['A12', 'U', 'C14', 'C', 'A'], ['A12', 'U', 'C', 'C14', 'A'],['A', 'U', 'C14', 'C', 'A12'], ['A', 'U', 'C', 'C14', 'A12']]
```

and convert to

```
output2 = [['*', 'U', '#', 'C', 'A'], ['*', 'U', 'C', '#', 'A'],['A', 'U', '#', 'C', '*'], ['A', 'U', 'C', '#', '*']]
```

I am using Python2.7 to solve this problem, but I have not figured it out yet... Any answer or suggestion will be appreciated!

Here is my code:

```
list1 = ['A', 'U', 'C', 'C', 'A']
list2 = ['12', '14']
key = {'A12':'*', 'C14':'#'}

list3 = ['12', '14', '0', '0','0'] #build by myself
combo = list(set(itertools.permutations(list3, len(list3))))
list_combo = []
for each_list in combo:
new_list = []
for i in xrange(len(list1)):
    if list1[i]+each_list[i] in key:
        new_list.append(key[list1[i]+each_list[i]])
    else:
        new_list.append(list1[i])
    list_combo.append(new_list)
print list_combo
```

There are some extra lists in the output, and if list2 or list3 is too big, it will take a lot of time to run itertools.permutations, so I am seeking another way to solve this problem.

Comment: Please mention what have you tried so far!

Comment: How do you transform the two lists into `output1`? Every combination of appending an element of `list2` before a duplicate element in `list1`? It looks almost random.

Comment: I was trying to use itertools.permutations, and applied this function to a new list3 = ['12', '14', '0', '0', '0'], and get different combinations, and then combine each element in list1 and lists, if list1[i]+list3[i] in the key, then I convert list1[i] to the value in the key. The problem is that if the number of list is too large, it will take a lot of time to run itertools.permutations, so I am seeking other way to do this.

Comment: @Ningxi: Post your current code. Can you add more background? Your input and output seem almost completely unrelated.

Comment: Is there a specific pattern you are using when combining list1 and list2 to reach output1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok this is a little long, so bear with me.  The first step is constructing a dictionary to convert from letters to letters with numbers, ie `A` to `A12`, etc.

```
replacements = dict((k[0],k) for k in key.keys())
# replacements is equal to {'A': 'A12', 'C': 'C14'}
```

This makes things much simpler later.  The next step is building a list of all the indicies that need replacing and breaking those into sublists for each type of replacement.

```
indicies = [[i for i,x in enumerate(list1) if x == k] for k in replacements.keys()]
# indicies is equal to [[0, 4], [2, 3]]
```

Finally, we use `itertools.product` on the list of indices that need replacing to get each possible grouping, and then add them to the necessary output lists:

```
output1 = []
output2 = []
for group in itertools.product(*indicies):
    l = []
    l2 = []
    for i in range(len(list1)):
        l.append(list1[i] if i not in group else replacements[list1[i]])
        l2.append(list1[i] if i not in group else key[replacements[list1[i]]])
    output1.append(l)
    output2.append(l2)
print output1
print output2
```

This gives us our desired answers of:

```
[['A12', 'U', 'C14', 'C', 'A'], ['A12', 'U', 'C', 'C14', 'A'], ['A', 'U', 'C14', 'C', 'A12'], ['A', 'U', 'C', 'C14', 'A12']]
[['*', 'U', '#', 'C', 'A'], ['*', 'U', 'C', '#', 'A'], ['A', 'U', '#', 'C', '*'], ['A', 'U', 'C', '#', '*']]
```

One major difference between this code and the code that you are running is that my code only runs for exactly as many iterations as it needs to, so in the case of your sample data set, 4 times.  Your code seems like it runs at least at least certain parts `n!` times, where `n` is the size of `list1`, and is equal to 120 for your sample data set.  This is still likely to run for a while on extremely large data sets (as is the nature of this sort of problem), but will only scale up with the number of replacements it has to do, rather than the size of the data set overall.

Comment: Good job, I didn't think about grouping the indices ... yeah, I did realize my code will run n! time, but this is my solution so far.. thank you!